# How to fetch data using between with two columns in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Please help me to write sequelize function for below MYSQL query

```
select * from userCategory where 25 between minAge and maxAge;
```

A Table looks like below

```
userRecords
id         minAge     maxAge    category
1          11         20        category 1
2          21         30        category 2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `select * from userCategory where minAge < 25 and maxAge > 25;` ?

Comment: @alfasin Right now I am using like your method. But doubt is, can't we do this with `between`?

Comment: [`between`](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/between.php) takes a column and two values and checks that the value in the column is between these two values. What you want to do is exactly the opposite.

Comment: I came here with same problem, myValue between 2 fields - looks like isn't possible, we need to use two conditionals

Answer (score 3):

You cannot simply use `BETWEEN` as it requires a column name or a computed table (like `WITH`) for the left side of the SQL function

The simplest solution would be:

```
models.userCategory.findAll({
        where: {
            minAge: { [Op.lt]: 25 },
            maxAge: { [Op.gt]: 25 },
        }, 
      })
```

If you must use `BETWEEN` then sequelize will make your life much harder, as you will require to use `sequelize.literal('SELECT 25 as age')` to start with in order to have a pseudo table ... just so you can use `BETWEEN`?